# Having local file specified instead of remote

Tags: c++, wininet

Is there a way to specify local file (on my hardDrive) to WinInet functions, like for example, FtpGetFile? I would like to do it as I have limited broadband and as I expect lots of hits and misses while developing my software, I really wouldn't like to waste my broadband on it.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you, in the case of `FtpGetFile`, run a server locally ?

Comment: @kbok sorry for dumb question, but do I need special software to do what you've suggested?

Comment: Yes you do, you need a FTP server. Filezilla server should meet your needs : http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server

Answer (score 1):

The most thorough solution to meet your need is to have a FTP server run locally.

This allows you to make a better "as is" test, instead of hooking the call to `FtpGetFile`.

To install a local FTP Server, use [`FileZilla FTP server`](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server) or the excellent [`winscp`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_ftps_server).